# Trying to understand the question(well spaced points ?) better

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Let us have a sorted array of n numbers and we would like to find a well spaced set of C of them, More specifically, we want to get a subset $ S\subset T$ with |S| = C and with $min_{i,j  \in S,i\ne j} |i-j|$ as large as possible. Come up an algorithm for fining the best S.

What is the correct output if the sorted array as 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 and c is 3. What about if the sorted array as 1, 10, 11, 12, 23, 24, 25 and c is 3 ?
also appreciated any hints to approached this question if you clearly understand what the question is asking.

Comment: Have you tried simpler situations? What is the correct output if the sorted array is 1, 2, 3 and C is 2? What is the correct output if the sorted array is 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5  and C is 2 or 3? What is the correct output if the sorted array is 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6,7 and C is 2 or 3? How can you make the set as large as possible?

Comment: if the sorted array is 1,2,3 and c is 2, then output is (1,2); if sorted array is 1,2,3,4,5 and c is 3 , then output is (1,2,3); 
I don't think the question is asking to make the set as large as possible, it is asking to make |i-j| to be as larger as possible.

Comment: "output is (1,2); if sorted array is 1,2,3,4,5 and c is 3, then output is (1,2,3)"? Your typo? (1,3,5)?

Comment: "How can you make the set as large as possible?" My statement was incomplete. I meant, suppose the difference $\min_{i,j  \in S,i\ne j} |i-j|$ is given, how you make the set as large as possible? If you can make the largest such set, then you will know whether there is a subset with C elements.

Comment: not a typo, I have been trying to understand the question.

Comment: so the correct output is (1,3,5) if the sorted array is 1,2,3,4,5. that is because |1-3| and |3-5| is 2 and 2 is the largest diff as possible and i, j $\in S$ and i $\ne$j.

Comment: Yes, (1,3,5). Is the vague hint in my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct output if the sorted array as 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 and C is 3?

Let us try. How about (1,2,3)? Too closely together. We should push away 3. (1,2,6) looks more far apart. Hmm, (1,2) is not good. (1, 3, 6) is the best.

> What about if the sorted array as 1, 10, 11, 12, 23, 24, 25 and C is 3 ?

We should include the smallest and biggest numbers, 1 and 25. Then we should choose a number as close to the middle as possible. (1,12,25).

...

Let us analyze $\min_{i,j  \in S,i\ne j} |i-j|$. Suppose $S=\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_C\}$, where $a_k\le a_{k+1}$. Then
$$\min_{i,j  \in S,i\ne j} |i-j|=\min_{1\le k\lt C}|a_{k+1}-a_k|$$
since the difference between two non-adjacent numbers $a_k$ and $a_{k+t}$ must be greater than the difference between $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$.

So the minimum difference among numbers in $S$ seems in "reverse proportion" to the difference between the adjacent or nearby numbers of the given array.

I will leave the above as a hint. Hopefully it is enough for you to figure out the rest.

Comment: Can you explain what it really meant "$min_{i,j  \in S,i\ne j} |i-j|$ as large as possible "?
My understanding is that: i and j are the two smallest element in the set S, then their difference is as large as possible ?  isn't that contradiction ?

Comment: For example, if $S=\{1,4,6,8\}$. Then $(i,j)$ where $i,j\in S$ and $i\not=j$ can be $(1,4), (1,6), (1,8), (4,6), (4,8), (6,8)$. So $|i-j|$ is 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 2 respectively.  The min (which is shorthand for minimum)  of all $|i-j|$ is 2.  That minimum value, 2 takes place at (4,6) or (6,8).